# Laravel Polymorphic relationship on same table (different user managers)

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, relationship, database-migration

I have the users table, where each user can be assigned to a manager. I have 3 types of Managers (Country Manager, Area Manager and Fleet Manager). One Area manager can have many Fleet Manager and Country Manager, and one Country Manager can have many Fleet Manager. My users table have the columns fleet_manager_id, country_manager_id,area_manager_id that reference on id of users table. The question is that i don't know how to set a polymorphic relationship on same table. 
Migration:

```php
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('fleet_manager_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('fleet_manager_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->integer('country_manager_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('country_manager_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->integer('area_manager_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('area_manager_id')->references('id')->on('users');
});
```

My User Model:

```php
public function fleetManagers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'fleet_manager_id');
}

public function countryManager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'country_manager_id');
}

public function areaManager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'area_manager_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is the solution i've come so far:

```
public function managedByArea()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'area_manager_id');
}

public function area_manager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'area_manager_id');
}

public function managedByCountry()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'country_manager_id');
}

public function country_manager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'country_manager_id');
}
public function managedByFleet()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'fleet_manager_id');
}

public function fleet_manager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'fleet_manager_id');
}
```